# Robocopy /RH Run End Time Parameter

Tags: powershell, command-line, robocopy

I am trying to understand parameters for Robocopy parameter **/rh:hhmm-hhmm** .

"Specifies run times when new copies may be started."

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy

```
robocopy C:\Source   C:\Destination   /MIR  /rh:1500-1800 .
```

Does that mean job starts at certain time, and if does not complete by end time, it will stop? So if it has a 100 files to copy, and only 50 are copied by 3:00 pm (1800), it will stop?

Comment: Questions about end-user software are more appropriate on https://superuser.com . Please read [Help On-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/On-topic) before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. According to [this article](https://windows.tips.net/T013219_Specifying_a_Copy_Schedule_in_Robocopy.html), Robocopy will only do its copying within the specified time frame. It will pause copying on reaching the end time.

> using the /RH:hhmm-hhmm switch. This tells Robocopy that it can only copy files between the hours/minutes of the first "hhmm" and the second "hhmm". There are, of course, three scenarios here.
>
> 1)
>   If the timeframe specified with /RH has already passed, Robocopy will remain paused until the time occurs the next day.
>
> 2) 
>   If the current system time is within the boundaries established with /RH then the copy occurs immediately.
>
> 3)
>   Finally, if the timeframe specified with /RH is in the future, Robocopy remains paused until the time occurs, and then the copy is performed.

Comment: thanks, have another question here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56350801/robocopy-rh-multiple-run-time-parameter